# TERADATA : SQL Assistant Preferences Backup/Restore

Tags: sql, preferences, teradata

I am using SQL Assistant as my workbench for TERADATA.
Recently, my system crashed and i had to setup the SQL assistant again.

SQL history was available in a MS Access DB file and i was able to save a lot of time as i had backed it up earlier.

However, i had a tough time with the following :

I had setup multiple preferences in SQL assistant including export paramter,date display format,etc.
All these preferences were gone after re-installation.
Is there an option for backup/restore of these preferences ??
There are multiple preferences and is convenient if those can also be restored with few clicks.

I am guessing that there should be a file where its stored. Not sure of concept or location.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to above issue.
The preferences file can be found at the following locations and can be backed up whenever required.

DataSources.config.
Toolbars.config
UserOptions.config : This is important considering the export/import options are changed by most users.

Following link explains in detail: [Teradata: SQL Assistant Backup/Restore Guide](http://allzhere.in/2013/10/06/teradata-sql-assistant-backuprestore-guide/)
I hope it helps.